# Someone has a chip on his shoulder? Inexplicable downvotes all over the place

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Whilst I can comprehend some uptight prude downvoting everything in a thread with awful words referring to breasts, I'm at a loss to understand all the answers downvoted in [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-singular-or-plural/9737#9737), which is discussing whether or not 'one' can be used in the plural.

Anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: I was the downvoter, and I downvoted the answers that were wrong or misleading. That's what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"all over the place"? Really? With a sample size of .. one? (I think the "breasts" question is a totally different case.)

I've told you a *million* times to stop exaggerating.

Comment: accepted & +1 for withering sarcasm >;-)

Comment: +1.  The sarcasm is literally killing me…

Answer (score 3):

Not all answers were downvoted, only some. And the ones that were are not all that great. I wouldn't downvote so easily, but I don't think it's worth being offended. If the answers are good, they'll be upvoted anyway.

Comment: Sorry to have given the wrong impression, the idea of being offended didn't even occur to me. There just seemed to be another spate of downvotes that prompted my curiousity

Comment: No problem, I also wanted to point out my own opinion, which is that why I wouldn't have downvoted these answers, I don't think it's blatantly inadequate.

Answer (score 2):

I also downvoted your answer. I should also point out that the question is discussing whether or not "minus one" can be used in the plural, not whether "one" can be used in the plural, as you say here.

Your examples are talking about the preposition "minus" and the noun "one" (or they appear to be — more context would help), but the question is about the noun "minus one".  Not addressing this distinction at all was part of the problem I had with your answer.

Also, saying "no exceptions" when there are people who clearly accept "-1 people" and don't like "-1 person" is a bit misleading.  Either you are ignoring the evidence that doesn't fit, or you are prescribing an answer based on your own internal logic, which people don't really go for on this site.

So now you have both downvotes accounted for.