# Has a clique of narrow-minded but self-important people gained enough power to exert a censorious control over content?

Tags: discussion, questions

i have been on this site for ten minutes and already received this message:

> **Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.**
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

is this one of those SE sites where a clique of narrow-minded but self-important people has gained enough power to exert a censorious control over content? i ask because if informed users suggest that is the case i will happily slope off to more favorable pastures and leave such people to continue their tyrannical rule in peace

ADDED this extract from a [previous question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/should-downvotes-require-comments?rq=1) by @Souta

*However, I've been noticing lately that answers to questions have been getting downvotes with no reasonable explanation. And not all of these answers being downvoted were bad at all. These answers were what OP was asking for, except in different words than other answers on a same question; that is how this site works. (These answers were, for the most part, valid; just not OP's preference.)*

Then, I've been noticing lately that questions are no longer receiving helpful comments for question improvement. Instead, they are being downvoted without giving OP some direction as to what can be said differently in the question.

I've quickly looked through meta to see if there had already been a question like this, and I did, but in the sense that other users were being harassed by downvotes...

Comment: In the ten minutes you were on the site, you posted one question that was closed as a duplicate and then a second that garnered downvotes. Then a third that was migrated to Meta. You must have hit the quality warning.

Comment: @KitFox a reasonable hypothesis. i've displayed too much enthusiasm and too little caution. i'll keep a lower profile.

Comment: I think you just need to leave a little more time between posting questions, is all.

Comment: @KitFox yes, i have many curiosities concerning language and was enthralled to find the site. but a more mature response would have been to remain, like stout Cortez, silent on this metaphorical peak of Darien. my first month on math SE was a running battle with anonymous downvoters and stylistic cavillers, but i survived, and perhaps the experience rubbed a few rough edges in my nature a little smoother. however the problem of censorious cliques is not negligeable. last week i read a physicist who depite 4000+ reputation points had decided to abandon physics SE for this reason

Comment: I was the first of (currently) three people who downvoted "When did people start writing **to** instead of **too**?", but I posted an explanatory comment saying exactly *why* I didn't think the question was suitable for ELU. I was also the first to closevote the earlier (duplicate) question, where I posted a "Welcome to ELU" comment and gave what I thought would be taken as friendly advice. But I'm now *downvoting* this question because I think OP's obviously hostile attitude is not conducive to a happy site.

Answer (score 15):

No, this is one of those SE sites where this is an automatic message completely automatically generated by the SE engine. And by "those SE sites" I mean "all SE sites".

Comment: thx @Reg for clarifying.